# Dumping Useful Data to Console on Caught Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, exception, console-application

I have a `CExceptionHandler` class that is invoked whenever my application detects a run-time exception.  For example:

```
if ( val == NULL )
{
    TRACE(_T("Unexpected NULL in sequence."));
    AfxThrowException( ERROR_INVALID_DATA );
}
```

`AfxThrowException` is very simple:

```
void AfxThrowException( DWORD error )
{
    CExceptionHandler * pException = NULL;

    if ( error == 0 )
    {
        error = ::GetLastError();
    }

    pException = new CExceptionHandler( error );

    TRACE(_T("Warning: throwing CSerialException for error %d\n"), error);
    THROW(pException);
}
```

This is the member `Dump` function of `CExceptionHandler`:

```
void CExceptionHandler::Dump( CDumpContext & dc ) const
{
    CObject::Dump(dc);

    dc << "m_dwError = " << m_dwError;
}
```

Higher up in my code I have the `try`/`catch` statements:

```
try
{
    /* My app does stuff where the exception is thrown. */
}
catch( CExceptionHandler * ex )
{
    afxDump << _T("Dumping exceptional data: ") << _T("\r\n");
    ex->Dump( afxDump );
    afxDump << _T("\r\n");
}
```

I would like the collected debug information to be dumped to the console.  However, when the PC gets into the `catch` statement (verified with breakpoint), nothing happens on the console.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 in Debug mode.  Thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a result you're throwing dynamically allocated memory? (Leaky.)

Comment: @GMan: Is there a result you're using "reason" instead of "result"? `:)` (Oh, and I think that's MFC to you. But my opinion on the matter is only from hearsay...)

Comment: A console?  This is MFC isn't it?  Try the Output window.

Comment: @Hans Passant: `CExceptionHandler` is MFC (.dll), but the application (.exe) is not (Win32 console project).

Comment: Hi Jim, I've updated my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CDumpContext` sends output to the debugger, not to the console (see [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362.aspx) for more information), and if you run under the Visual Studio debugger, the output will appear in the **Output** window.

If you want to also send output to the console, you can configure `CDumpContext` to write to a `CFile` by passing a pointer to a `CFile` object in the [`CDumpContext` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a0wzwf78.aspx).

If your application is built with the 'Use Multi-Byte Character Set' configuration option, you can use [`CStdioFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7b61hcx0.aspx) to write to either stdout or stderr:

```
CStdioFile file(stdout);
CDumpContext dumpContext(&file);
ex->Dump(dumpContext);
```

Or, if you want to use `afxDump`, you can set its `m_pFile` member variable directly (it's declared `public`). For example you could put this code inside your `main` function:

```
CStdioFile file(stdout);
afxDump.m_pFile = &file;
```

But, this won't work if your app is built as Unicode because strings need to be converted to multi-byte to be written to stdout. To do the conversion, write a class that inherits `CFile`:

```
class CDumpFile : public CFile
{
    public:
        virtual void Write(const void* lpBuf, UINT nCount);
};

void CDumpFile::Write(const void* lpBuf, UINT nCount)
{
    // Construct string from array of wide chars
    const wchar_t* p = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(lpBuf);
    UINT len = nCount / sizeof(wchar_t);
    CStringW str(p, len);

    CStringA astr(str); // Convert wide char to multibyte

    fputs((LPCSTR)astr, stdout); // Write multibyte string to stdout
}
```

and use it like this:

```
CDumpFile file;
afxDump.m_pFile = &file;
```

A couple of other points about your code:

1. You should ensure that the exception object is deleted in the `catch` block. If your `CExceptionHandler` class inherits MFC's `CException` then you should call `ex->Delete()`. If it doesn't, you need to `delete ex`.
2. I'd advise against using the `Afx` prefix for own functions - you should consider this reserved for use by the MFC library, in my opinion.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!  I implemented the solution using `CDumpContext dumpContext(&file)`, and it works for the most part.  However, it's spacing out the characters (`a   C E x c e p t i o n H a n d l e r   a t   $ 0 0 E 2 4 E 4 0     m _ d w E r r o r   =   1 7 0 `.  Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Yes, it's because `CStdioFile` is writing `wchar_t` strings to the console, which is expecting MBCS. See my updated answer.